# Developing Formula/Pattern To Determine Position

Tags: javascript, formula

I'll try to ask as clearly as possible, but please comment if some part is not clear to you.

I'm trying to develop a formula to determine the position of an element based on that element's value in a sequence. More specifically, I am using JavaScript to split a string of this nature: `c-c c-c-c c` into an array and iterate over that array using an interval of **2i** to extract the **c** values. For example, let's say my string is as previously posted (6 c values in length). I wish to place these **c** values in the following manner where the number refers to the value of **i** in my loop (I prepended an extra 0 to make it symmetrical due to the 10):

```
00 ## 02
      ##
06 ## 04
##
08 ## 10
```

I'm trying to find a pattern/formula using the value of **i** which will result in the above positioning. For simplicity's sake, let's assume an x,y coordinate system such that the position of the **c** value at `00` is (0,0), `02` is (1,0), `04` is (1,1), `06` is (0,1), `08` is (0,2), and `10` is (1,2).

Can anyone help in developing a pattern/formula/algorithm to determine the positioning using **i** values? I'm trying not to have to write (in this example) six different if statements.

Comment: How does `c-c c-c-c c` turn into your above image?

Comment: Ignore the spaces and hyphens between the characters for now (that's a problem I will figure out at a later point). The i value in my for loop for each **c** is referenced in my "image" and the **##** represents the space or hyphen. I included the **##**'s to indicate the flow/positioning that needs to be attained.

Comment: But where is this backwards **S** coming from? Or are you just trying to figure out the position of the `i`th block if this snake went on this way forever?

Comment: Exactly! That is where the "shape" is coming from. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your x,y coordinate system:

```
y = Math.floor(i / 2);
x = y % 2 == 0 ? i % 2 : (i + 1) % 2;
```

Or if you want it more concise (but very unclear):

```
y = Math.floor(i / 2);
x = (i + y % 2) % 2;
```

---

The above code is based on the assumption that the code is something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theString.length / 2; i++) {
    var character = theString.charAt(2 * i);
    // work out the coordinates
}
```

If the code is more like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i += 2) {
    var character = theString.charAt(i);
    // work out the coordinates
}
```

Then we need to do modify it a bit to be like this:

```
j = i / 2;
y = Math.floor(j / 2);
x = y % 2 == 0 ? j % 2 : (j + 1) % 2;
```

Or if you want it more concise (but very unclear):

```
j = i / 2;
y = Math.floor(j / 2);
x = (j + y % 2) % 2;
```

Comment: That's because your question contradicts itself.  I based this on you saying you used an interval of 2i, but now that I've reread it I realise that you're probably not doing that at all.  I'll post a different version in a minute